# How to create different page styles in drupal 7 site?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-blocks

i want to make drupal pages that has got different structures. Like on
 the first page i want to place many 'views blocks', and after pages i
 want to show other banners and some other blocks not placed on other
 pages.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to admin/structure/block and click "configure" on the block.

Towards the bottom, there's a 'Pages' tab where you can indicate what pages you would like to show this block on.

For front page, use `<front>`

For other pages, use the path after http://yourdomain.com/  i.e. node/1

This box also supports wild cards, so if you wanted a block to show on all node pages, you could use: `node/*`

Comment: then how would you change where its positioned on the page?